# Update AngularJS models from a jQuery plugin with a “on visible” callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, keyboard, visible

Update AngularJS models from a jQuery plugin with a “on visible” callback

I want recuprer el.value in keybord visible function

```
 .directive('keyboard', function () {
     return {

         restrict: 'C',
         link: function (scope, element, attr) {
             $(element).keyboard({
                 usePreview: false,
                 stickyShift: false,
                 autoAccept: true,
                 layout: 'custom',
                 display: {
                     'clear': 'vider :Clear',
                 },
                 customLayout: {
                     'default': [
                         'a z e r t y u i o p',
                         'q s d f g h j k l m',
                         'w x c v b n é è {del}',
                         '{clear} {space} {cancel} {b}'
                     ]
                 },
                 visible: function (e, keyboard, el) {
                     scope.newUser= el.value;
                 }
                 // ...
```

it works

```
  change: function (e, keyboard, el) {
      scope.newUser= el.value;
  }
```

But I want visible

Comment: Maybe `scope.$apply(function() {scope.newUser = el.value;})`?

Comment: I tried but its not working

Comment: how i can implement this solution in my code